# Google Puzzle Euler Number

Tags: python, eulers-number

This post is twofold.
I am a neophyte to Python.

#### First part.

This is my code for the old Google puzzle:
'First 10 digit prime number in the consecutive digits of e' 
(https://google-tale.blogspot.ca/2008/07/google-billboard-puzzle.html)

```
euler = '7182818284590452353602874713526624977572470936999595749669676277240766303535475945713821785251664274274663919320030599218174135966290435729003342952605956307381323286279434907632338298807531952510190115738341879307021540891499348841675092447614606680822648001684774118537423454424371075390777449920695517027618386062613313845830007520449338265602976067371132007093287091274437470472306969772093101416928368190255151086574637721112523897844250569536967707854499699679468644549059879316368892300987931277361782154249992295763514822082698951936680331825288693984964651058209392398294887933203625094431173012381970684161403970198376793206832823764648042953118023287825098194558153017567173613320698112509961818815930416903515988885193458072738667385894228792284998920868058257492796104841984443634632449684875602336248270419786232090021609902353043699418491463140934317381436405462531520961836908887070167683964243781405927145635490613031072085103837505101157477041718986106873969655212671546889570350354'


for i in range(len(euler) - 3):
    if (euler[i + 3]== '1' or euler[i + 3]== '3' or euler[i + 3]== '7' or euler[i + 3]== '9'):
        number = int(euler[i:i + 3])
        for a in range(2, round(number**0.5)):
           if number % a == 0:
             break
        else:
           print(number),
           break
```

So strangely using the code above I can find the correct answer which is 7427466391 (it takes 45mn to compile) but when I test the code for 3 digits it gives me 709 which is incorrect because the first 3-digits prime number is 281 range(3,6).

How can I fix this?

#### Second part.

This is an algorithm which is supposed to be the fastest to find a prime number (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test) (see pseudo-code in the middle of the page). This is my code but it doesn't work, I enter into an infinite loop.

```
for i in range(len(euler) - 3):
    if (euler[i + 3]== '1' or euler[i + 3]== '3' or euler[i + 3]== '7' or euler[i + 3]== '9'):
        number = int(euler[i:i + 3])
        for y in range(2, number-1):
            while y * y <= number:
                if (number % y != 0 or  number % (y+1) != 0):
                break
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, replace *'3'* with *'2'* so that it checks the 3rd digit for oddness, instead of the 4th:

```
euler[i + 3]== '1' or euler[i + 3]== '3' or euler[i + 3]== '7' or euler[i + 3]== '9'):
```

changes to

```
euler[i + 2]== '1' or euler[i + 2]== '3' or euler[i + 2]== '7' or euler[i + 2]== '9'):
```

Similarly, think about what the range in the for loop should stretch to (i.e. len - 2 or len -3), even if it does not apply to this example.

In general, avoid using [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) at all. Define a variable or accept an input to set N = 3 or 10...

Also, you don't gain much by adding the `if` condition, only the potential for bugs (as above). *Premature optimization is the root of all evil*

For the second part, when you `break` your inner loop, you don't really establish any primality. You could do something simple like setting a flag. Here, I've modified your program to provide one example:

```
euler = '7182818284590452353602874713526624977572470936999595749669676277240766303535475945713821785251664274274663919320030599218174135966290435729003342952605956307381323286279434907632338298807531952510190115738341879307021540891499348841675092447614606680822648001684774118537423454424371075390777449920695517027618386062613313845830007520449338265602976067371132007093287091274437470472306969772093101416928368190255151086574637721112523897844250569536967707854499699679468644549059879316368892300987931277361782154249992295763514822082698951936680331825288693984964651058209392398294887933203625094431173012381970684161403970198376793206832823764648042953118023287825098194558153017567173613320698112509961818815930416903515988885193458072738667385894228792284998920868058257492796104841984443634632449684875602336248270419786232090021609902353043699418491463140934317381436405462531520961836908887070167683964243781405927145635490613031072085103837505101157477041718986106873969655212671546889570350354'

for i in range(len(euler) - 2):
    if (euler[i + 2]== '1' or euler[i + 2]== '3' or euler[i + 2]== '7' or euler[i + 2]== '9'):
        number = int(euler[i:i + 3])
        for y in range(2, number-1):
            isPrime = True
            while y * y <= number:
                if (number % y != 0 or  number % (y+1) != 0):
                  isPrime = False # The number is not prime
                  break  # Exit loop

            if isPrime:  # Nothing was able to factorize the number
              print(number) # Print and leave
              exit(0)
```

However, your code is really quite broken and could do with a lot of attention and testing of the different edge cases.

Comment: Thanks very much @Jedi. Definitely my code needs improvement, this is my 3rd week of a Python course I am taking online so thanks for your understanding!

Answer (score 0):

For your first part, you are grasping the right-end non-inclusive property of range and slicing in Python. However, when you are just indexing to find an element, should you still care about that or not? By that I mean, is the third digit really indexed at `i+3` for a number starting at position `i`?

For your second part, I am not quite seeing the mapping between your code and the pseudo-code.

Tips in general. You can compartmentalize the prime_check logic into a function that returns True or False, and call the function each time you get a number, then decide whether you want to print it and break or continue. Also, the comparisons you are doing for 1, 3, 7, 9 and be abbreviated with an `in`.

Comment: Thanks @CaptainMeow for your helpful comment!

Comment: Yes that's true, the mapping between my code and the pseudo-code is not accurate. I had paste the wrong code. Thanks also for indicating the difference between the non-inclusive property of range that is absent when indexing.